# In NTFS, what's the difference between sector size, block size and cluster size?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

For example, I have a volume with the following info extracted from `ntfsinfo`:

```
$ sudo ntfsinfo -m /dev/sdb1
Volume Information
        Name of device: /dev/sdb1
        Device state: 11
        Volume Name: Photos 250GB
        Volume State: 27
        Volume Version: 3.1
        Sector Size: 512
        Cluster Size: 65536
        Index Block Size: 4096
        Volume Size in Clusters: 3815583
```

which was previously created via:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -c 65536 -Q -L "Photos 250GB" /dev/sdb1
```

I've read that **cluster size** is the same as **allocation unit size** in Windows. And so I'm expecting files to take up at least 64KB, as it would in Windows. However, this doesn't seem to be apparent from invoking `stat` on a small file:

```
$ stat lsfsdf
  File: `lsfsdf'
  Size: 9               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 80          Links: 1
```

I'm trying to make sense out of it all, and so wish know what *sector size*, *cluster size* and *index block size* are in the volume information output by `ntfsinfo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sector size" describes the size of the atomic unit of the storage device itself. "Cluster size" descries the atomic unit of NTFS allocation for non-resident streams (see below). Index blocks are used to store directories. "Index block size" describes the size of the atomic unit of index block storage.

You're seeing sub-cluster allocation for small files because of resident streams. Small files are stored directly in the master file table (MFT) (a ["resident stream"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Resident_vs._non-resident_data_streams)) and do not require a cluster to be allocated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've verified that the number of blocks do become 128 (128*512=65536) upon reaching a file size of 600+, and interestingly 2 just right before the threshold. By the way, is the index block size of 4096 a fixed parameter for any given device (or specific to ntfs maybe)? I don't see any parameter for changing it in mkfs.ntfs.

Comment: The index block size is a stored parameter that could be changed but I'm not aware of any mechanism in Windows (the canonical NTFS implementation) to do so. I think you'd be risking compatibility w/ Windows if you did tweak it.

Comment: I'm not sure what Windows will do with this information, or what tools I could use to check these values there, but mkfs.ntfs allows me to specify a sector size independently from the cluster size (but requires cluster size >= sector size). I understand that disks have a set physical sector size, and that some even have a configurable logical sector size. What I don't understand is why mkfs.ntfs has configurable sector size, and why `ntfsinfo -m` reports the sector size I configured, and not either of the disk sector sizes. Any insights?

Comment: Ah ha! Had I simply rebooted into Windows rather than scouring the net for answers, I would have discovered sooner that on a 512e/4Kn drive Windows believes that an ntfs partition created with `mkfs.ntfs -s 4096` is a "RAW" partition, and refuses to dskchk or mount it. So while Linux NTFS tools may be happy with that forced sector size that matches the drive's physical sector size (and indeed I can read the data on it), Windows is not. Cluster size via `mkfs.ntfs -c` is a different matter, and should probably be >= drive physical sector size.